# Internet Archive Book Reader for HTML5 not flash

Tags: javascript, html

hi all
i am new to do this.
I am trying to get around Book Reader from Internet Archive

The documentation and downloading link are in the following links:
http://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/bookreader
http://raj.blog.archive.org/2011/03/17/how-to-serve-ia-style-books-from-your-own-cluster/

once the source code is downloaded, I had a look at the JavaScript file called BookReaderJSSimple.js inside BookReaderDemo where in line 19 it mentions about changing the path to retrieve images.

But I am not sure how to do this.

Suppose I have images inside a folder labbeled as 1.jpg then 2.jpg....continues

how would I code it for Javascript

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is best if you name your images 001.jpg, 002.jpg, etc.

Then, in br.getPageURI (line 28), you can set the url to your images.

For example, if the images are available on your server at the following URL:
http://my.example.com/images/001.jpg

then set line 28 to be:

```
var url = 'http://my.example.com/images/'+leafStr.replace(re, imgStr) + '.jpg';
```

Hope that helps!